# How to undo the changes done in OnPaint Event in Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have drawn a region in C# Winform onPaint event. I dont want to have these changes in full screen mode. I have tried to save and restore the graphics but not able to do, please let me know if I'm missing something.

```
//class member
bool mFullSize = false;
    GraphicsState transState;
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{

    base.OnPaint(e);

 // Save translated graphics state.


    Graphics gr = e.Graphics;
    transState = gr.Save();
    int x = 50;
    int y = 50;
    int width = 100;
    int height = 100;

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width / 2, height / 2);
    Region region = new Region(rect);

    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddPie(x, y, width, height, 180, 90);
    region.Exclude(path);

    if (!mFullSize)
    {
        gr.FillRegion(Brushes.Black, region);
    }
    else
    {
        gr.Restore(transState);
    }

}


 protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
    {
        mFullSize = true;
    }
    else
    {
        mFullSize = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply return when the Form is full sized? It's painted on maximization anyway, so I don't see no need to (re-)store any graphics state.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized) return; // just don't paint the things you don't want to

    Graphics gr = e.Graphics;
    int x = 50;
    int y = 50;
    int width = 100;
    int height = 100;

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width / 2, height / 2);
    Region region = new Region(rect);

    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddPie(x, y, width, height, 180, 90);
    region.Exclude(path);

    gr.FillRegion(Brushes.Black, region);
}
```

**UPDATE:** The problem is `OnResize` is not called when maximizing. You need to use `OnSizeChanged` or simply check the `WindowState` directly in your `OnPaint` method.

**UPDATE2:** First update was not completely correct (bug in debug-messages). `OnResize` is actually called. But you forgot to call `base.OnResize` and so `OnPaint` is not called.

So be sure to call `base.OnResize` in your overload. In your `OnPaint` you can check the `WindowState` directly and avoid painting if your Form is maximized.

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    // DON'T FORGET TO CALL THE BASE METHOD
    base.OnResize(e);
    mFullSize = this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Comment: "not working" is not so helpful...what's happening? Maybe you need to call `Invaildate()`  in your `OnResize` method when switched to full screen. (But I'm pretty sure the window is painted after a resize).

Comment: it has not effect, drawn image is shown in both case.

Comment: @vivekjain: Updated answer, use `OnSizeChanged` instead of `OnResize`.

Comment: its giving the same result.

Comment: Can't reproduce it here. It works perfectly fine for me (without `OnResize` or `OnSizeChanged`, only with `OnPaint` and checking `WindowState` directly).

Comment: yes, your code is working fine, but without OnResize event, Actually I must have to use OnResize event for some other work, so I cannot delete my existing OnResize event.

Comment: @vivekjain Huh? That has nothing to do with painting. But maybe I spot a bug: You probably need to call `base.OnResize` in your overload (though as I said it seems not to be called at all on maximization).

Comment: @vivekjain corrected my answer (and tested with `OnResize` without call to `base.OnResize`, so I reproduced your bug successfully).

Comment: I dont know why OnPaint is not getting called in my code :(

Comment: Because `OnPaint` is called from the base class's `OnResize`, which isn't called because you've overwritten `OnResize` without calling `base.OnResize()`